# Find all columns that have emails in data oracle

Tags: oracle

I am going to start off by apologizing because I don't know how to put my problem into words.

i have a database with about 15000 columns and I want to find every column that has emails stored in it. I've tried searching through column names but that isn't helping because there is so much variation.

i want to do something like this

select column_name from all_tab_cols where data like '%@%.com%

this is on an oracle database but I am accessing the data through tableau.

Thanks,
Aayush

Clarification: I want to find every column that has an email address in it.

Comment: That is one of the strangest requirements I've seen. Suppose you can find all the columns that contain email addresses. How are you going to use that information? Then: You must clarify. Do you want to find the columns that contain at least one email address (in at least one row)? Or only the columns that contain email addresses (or perhaps `null`) in **every** row in the table? Of course, selecting only `column_name` serves no purpose (you may have columns with the same name in different tables), and in any case you can't do it like you show; you will need dynamic SQL.

Comment: There is 1 (out of 1500) table with 1 column (out of 15000) that has no data but emails in it. i don;t know how to find it.

Comment: I would do something like Brian Leach shows in his answer - write a small PL/SQL program that will look for that column. For each table I would select perhaps 10-20 random rows and count, for each column, how many times the @ symbol appears. Then I would focus on the few columns with the highest counts of @.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only find email addresses that end with @something.com, but you are looking for something like what is below. There have been other posts about finding email addresses, it is very difficult to do:

```
DECLARE
    l_cmd     VARCHAR2 (2000);
    l_found   INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR eachcol IN (  SELECT *
                        FROM all_tab_cols a
                       WHERE a.data_type = 'VARCHAR2'
                         AND owner = 'SEARCHSCHEMANAME'
                    ORDER BY table_name, column_name)
    LOOP
        l_cmd   :=
               'select count(*) c from '
            || eachcol.owner
            || '.'
            || eachcol.table_name
            || ' where '
            || LOWER (eachcol.column_name)
            || q'[ LIKE '%@%.com%' AND ROWNUM = 1]';

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_cmd INTO l_found;

        IF l_found > 0
        THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                   RPAD (eachcol.owner || '.' || eachcol.table_name || '.' || eachcol.column_name, 92)
                || ' may contain email addresses'
            );
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (l_cmd);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (SQLERRM);
        RAISE;
END;
```